# How do I edit this contract to remove the fee payment and mint a new token?

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-20

So I have a contract, What I wanna do?

1. Remove the payment fee;
2. Replace variables to deploy my own token;

Here is the original contract

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x794e3d275ded78da483367359806cf394ffa46ed#contracts

1. (Remove fee) Im beginner in solidity, but I guess I should remove the 469 line which is:

   ```
    feeReceiver.transfer(msg.value);
   ```
2. (Replace and mint a new token) I don't know what to do, I guess I need just change variables in constructor (Lines 451-456)?

```
constructor(string memory name, string memory symbol, uint8 decimals, uint256 totalSupply, address payable feeReceiver, address tokenOwnerAddress) public payable {
      _name = name;
      _symbol = symbol;
      _decimals = decimals;

      // set tokenOwnerAddress as owner of all tokens
      _mint(tokenOwnerAddress, totalSupply);

      // pay the service fee for contract deployment
      feeReceiver.transfer(msg.value);
    }
```

to:

```
constructor(string memory name, string memory symbol, uint8 decimals, uint256 totalSupply, address payable feeReceiver, address tokenOwnerAddress) public payable {
      _name = "Token Example";
      _symbol = "TE";
      _decimals = 18;

      // set tokenOwnerAddress as owner of all tokens
      _mint(0x000000000000000, 300000000000000);

      // pay the service fee for contract deployment
      feeReceiver.transfer(msg.value); (and delete this to stop fee payment)
    }
```

But gives *Unused function parameter remove or comment the variable*, I can't figure out whats a happening

Comment: This is a ton of code. Please paste the relevant parts **within the question** and **in plain text** (no links or images).

Comment: @goodvibration updated!

Comment: Are you a beginner in Solidity or a beginner in general? The compiler tells you that parameter `totalSupply` is unused because it is... well, unused.

Comment: @goodvibration So then the total amount of supply should be written within the scope of the function? Not in `_mint(tokenOwnerAddress, totalSupply);` ? Can you please help me with this?

Comment: Well, now that you've changed `_mint(myaddressnumber, totalsuplynumber)` to `_mint(tokenOwnerAddress, totalSupply)`, it looks fine on that aspect.

Comment: Why on earth are you minting to address 0? No one will ever be able to claim these tokens?

Comment: @goodvibration Just a example :)

Comment: @goodvibration So if it's fine should I ignore these warnings in remix?

Comment: `Replace variables to deploy my own token;` - you don't need to change anything in the code. You only need to deploy the contract with different constructor-argument values.

Comment: @goodvibration this is the tokemint.io template contract you have to pay 0.1 ether to mint so I want to undertand how it works :)

Comment: @goodvibration >You only need to deploy the contract with different constructor-argument values. How I do that in Remix? Too newbie..

Comment: @goodvibration also thanks for the help!

Comment: I think I get it!

Comment: I went to deployer in remix and it asks the constructor fields to fill,  it's right?